# Querying XML Without Worrying about Namespaces

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have XML with and without a prefix on elements, but no namespaces defined for any of them.  When I try to load this, it gives me an error on XDocument.Load (at least, I think that's where it happens) that certain prefixes are not defined.  Is there a way to tell the framework to ignore any namespace prefixes?  I'm using LINQ to XML, but could use something else if available.

I can't necessarily pre-define them because I'm going to be working with a variety of documents that may or may not have a prefix defined and no definitive xmlns declaration.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/

Comment: Processing XML without worrying about namespaces is equivalent to "processing XML without worrying about XML".

Comment: Yup.  I agree, but it's an XML-based document where I only need to worry about the tag.

Comment: No, you need to worry about the entire document, or you wouldn't be asking this question.

Comment: Worry about parsing the tags themselves is what I meant to say.

Comment: You are proving that you don't understand XML when you talk in terms of "just parsing the tags".

Comment: @John c'mon, really?  Yes, its not real XML. I don't need to treat it as XML, but essentially I need a glorified element/attribute reader, and trying to treat it as an XML document seems to be the best bet.

Comment: XML documents have elements which may be in namespaces. You pays your money and you takes your namespaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aren't prefixes supposed to represent an abbreviation for a namespace? I believe you need to clean up those prefixes that have no namespace associated with them in the first place before processing it, since it isn't valid XML. A quick regex to replace all prefixes of the form </prefix: with </: and <prefix: with < should do it.

To do this, first replace the following regex matches
`</.*?:` with `</`
and `<.*?:` with `<` (do not change the ordering).

Comment: Good idea, I might go this route instead.

Answer (score 1):

An approach to what you want to do may be using `XmlDocument`:

```
XmlDocument d = new XmlDocument();
using (var textReader = new XmlTextReader(@"test.xml"))
{
    textReader.Namespaces = false;
    d.Load(textReader);
}
```

You will lose the power of querying the data using the syntax of LINQ to XML.

You can actually use LINQ to XML and ignore the namespace by setting for each prefix in the file the folowing line

`nameSpaceManager.AddNamespace("prefixName", "urn:ignore");` 
where `nameSpaceManager` is of type `XmlNamespaceManager`. 
But from your question i sense that this is not a reasonable solution.